# Unable to use Arrays on Typescript 3.1 with Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to use a types array for an application using Typescript 3.1.1 Angular 7.. There seems to be something I am missing. So I tried a simple string array and even that doesn't seem to work for me.. Not sure what I am missing..

```
let array: string[] = [];

array.push("test"); //<--- doesn't work. :(
```

This results in the exception:

```
[ts] Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Comment: Is there possibly anything else called `array` that's conflicting with your definition?

Comment: I did a search and couldn't find any other references of ``array``.. :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There's nothing wrong with the code you posted; this means something else must be going on, but you haven't provided enough information for anyone else to identify what that might be.  Please review the guidelines for what constitutes a [mcve] so we can hopefully give you a more meaningful answer.